# scalaz - type mismatch

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am facing 'type mismatch' issue, I tried more than two hours even not resolved because I am not good in scala.

**Using:**
   **Scala 2.11.7**

**Error:**

```
[error] AlertUUU.scala:297: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalaz.Validation StartTimeOverlap.type, OnPeakRange]
[error]  required: scalaz.Validation[String,OnPeakRange]
[error]       p.onPeakRanges.find(x ⇒ opr.startTime >= x.startTime && opr.startTime <= x.stopTime).map
```

(_.startTimeOverlap).getOrElse(opr.success)

**Code:**

```
  def startTimeMustNotOverlap(p: UUUPeriod, opr: OnPeakRange): Validation[String, OnPeakRange] =
  p.onPeakRanges.find(x ⇒ opr.startTime >= x.startTime && opr.startTime <= x.stopTime).map(_.startTimeOverlap).getOrElse(opr.success)


case class OnPeakRange(
                        startTime: Int,
                        stopTime: Int,
                        originalThreshold: Int) extends OnPeakRangeT with OnPeakRangeValidations {
  def startTimeOverlap = OnPeakRange.StartTimeOverlap.failure
  def stopTimeOverlap = OnPeakRange.StopTimeOverlap.failure
  def allHoursPeakNotFullDay = OnPeakRange.AllHoursPeakNotFullDay.failure
}

case object StartTimeOverlap extends ValidationKey

trait ValidationKey {
  def failNel = this.toString.failureNel
  def nel = NonEmptyList(this.toString)
  def fail = this.toString.failure
}
```

Comment: Can you please better detail your data structure? `OnPeakRange` and `UdmPeriod`.

Comment: I added both with need fields.

Comment: Updated my answer to cope with that...

Answer (score 2):

The error explains everything, `startTimeMustNotOverlap` should return a `Validation[String, OnPeakRange]`.

Your `Success` case is of type `OnPeakRange`, your `Failure` type is of case `OnPeakRange.StartTimeOverlap` instead of a `String`.

You have to just change the type of `startTimeOverlap` to `String` or change the `Validation` type.

---

```scala
def startTimeMustNotOverlap(p: Period, opr: OnPeakRange): Validation[String, OnPeakRange] =
  p.onPeakRanges.find(
    x => opr.startTime >= x.startTime && opr.startTime <= x.stopTime
  ).fold(opr.success[String])(_.startTimeOverlap)

case class Period(onPeakRanges: List[OnPeakRange] = Nil)
case class OnPeakRange(startTime: Int, stopTime: Int){
  def startTimeOverlap = "...".failure
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Federico,   I tried but even I am getting same issue  [error]  found   : scalaz.Validation[OnPeakRange.StartTimeOverlap.type,Nothing]
[error]  required: scalaz.Validation[String,OnPeakRange]
[error]       p.onPeakRanges.find(x ⇒ opr.startTime >= x.startTime && opr.startTime <= x.stopTime).fold(opr.success[String])(_.startTimeOverlap).getOrElse(opr.success)
I changed my post with clear details. Please need help....

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
def startTimeOverlap = OnPeakRange.StartTimeOverlap.failure
```

to

```
def startTimeOverlap = OnPeakRange.StartTimeOverlap.fail
```